# What are my options for securely identifying HTTP requests originating from Azure App Service?

Tags: http, azure, azure-web-app-service

If I use [flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) to build and send an HTTP request from one Azure App Service (formerly Web Sites) to another App Service instance, is there any TCP/IP or HTTP-level information that I can use to quickly & easily trust the request?

Specific examples of what I'm looking for would be:

- Custom HTTP headers appended automatically by Azure App Service
- Known IP address ranges

This is obviously in an effort to not have to maintain a shared secret as I don't feel it's necessary when communicating within the same data centre.

Comment: Indeed there is a way. See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38726543/4148708

Answer (score 0):

> Specific examples of what I'm looking for would be: Custom HTTP headers appended automatically by Azure App Service; Known IP address ranges

If you’d like to set custom headers (such as authorization header) for request, you could try to use **WithHeader** method to set request headers. For more information, please refer to "**Configuring Client Calls**" section in [this documentation](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/).

```
url.WithHeader("someheader", "foo")
```

Besides, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503013/how-to-preserve-headers-in-the-flurl-httpclient) discussed about set request headers, you could refer to it.

Comment: I know I can add my own headers to my requests.  But I'm just wondering if any are automatically added to outbound requests by Azure App Service that I can rely on, rather than coming up with my own setup.  Just trying to avoid redundancy.